# Dropdown menu for price and team

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I am making the website for the college tech fest, in that I want to display the drop down menu of price and the team menu whenever any person selects the event corresponding dropdown menu must be seen.

For example:

If the person selects abc event then the price of that event depending on the number of persons in the team. If the price is 50 for event and the person is registers for team of 2 then price must be 100.

Preferred languages:

PHP
JQUERY

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select`and `option` tags to create frop down menu ([tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)). Then you can modify the other drop down menu using javascript.

JQuery is not a programming language, it's javascript library. However, jQuery is good tool to do this kind of things.

Here is quick demonstration:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h0jpb4xg/)